# Switch statement object to int problems

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, switch-statement

I am trying to use the `selectedItem` command to see what has been selected in the list box and then use the switch to set the `activityLevel` variable depending on what has been selected. I then need to be able to multiply that variable by the `BMR` variable that is set as a double. Then the result is displayed in a label.

```
string activityLevel = lstActivityLevel.SelectedItem.ToString();
switch (activityLevel)
{
    case 1:
        activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL2);
        break;

    case 2:
        activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL3);
        break;

    case 3:
        activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL4);
        break;

    case 4:
        activityLevel = Convert.ToInt32(ACTIVTY_LEVEL5);
        break;
}
//Display BMR in label
lblBMRResult.Text = (BMR*activityLevel).ToString();
```

Comment: What is your question? And what data type is the listbox populated with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SelectedIndex`, then each item of `lstActivityLevel` set to number from 0 to 4:

```
double activityLevel = 0;
switch (lstActivityLevel.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL1;
        break;

    case 1:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL2;
        break;

    case 2:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL3;
        break;

    case 3:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL4;
        break;

    case 4:
        activityLevel = ACTIVTY_LEVEL5;
        break;
}
lblBMRResult.Text = (BMR * activityLevel).ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You convert SelectedItem value to string. And value 1 (int) is not the same as "1" (string)... So, you have to change your switch statement to:

```
switch (activityLevel)
{
  case "1":
    blah, blah...
    break;
}
```

and so on..

Or do not call ToString() on SelectedItem.

Or you can use SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem..